# How to execute ajax if page is load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to display the database table using php. When the page is loaded I need to show all table data and when I select the dropdown select, I neeed to display only data related to it ie.using where condition. I don't need any sql query or php code for it, I just need jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#myHref').change(function()
    {
                var value = $('#myHref').val();
                $.get('get_projectName.php',{id:value},function(data)
                { 
                    $('#projectDetail').html(data);
                }); 
    }); 
    $('#myHref').on('change',function()
    {
        $('#projectDetail').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Here when I select drop down menu `id="myHref"` execute `get_projectName.php`, but I need to execute `get_projectName.php` when page is load before select dropdown so I can display all data

Plz Help!!

Comment: so you can use inside javascript like `var get_prj = <?php echo " ' ".include('get_projectName.php')." ' "?> ;`

Comment: So if you want to execute the `get_projectName.php` before the change event, what will you pass as Id??

Comment: share html as well

Answer (score 2):

> bt I need to execute get_projectName.php when page is load before select dropdown so i can display all data

So I see you want to initially load execute `get_projectName.php` once when page loads and also execute it if there are any changes in the dropdown. So you can do like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //make a call initially on page load
    var firstOptionValue = $("#myHref option:eq(1)").val() // take first option value as default
    $.get('get_projectName.php',{id:firstOptionValue},function(data)
    { 
      $('#projectDetail').html(data);
    }); 


    $('#myHref').change(function(){
        var value = $('#myHref').val();
        $.get('get_projectName.php',{id:value},function(data)
        { 
          $('#projectDetail').html(data);
        }); 
    }); 

    $('#myHref').on('change',function(){
      $('#projectDetail').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

---

**Refactoring the code**, you can just pull out the common logic into a function and call that function by passing the required value, See below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //make a call initially on page load
    var firstOptionValue = $("#myHref option:eq(1)").val(); // take first option value as default
    GetProjectDetails(firstOptionValue);


    $('#myHref').change(function(){
        var value = $('#myHref').val();
        GetProjectDetails(value);
    }); 

    $('#myHref').on('change',function(){
      $('#projectDetail').fadeIn();
    });

    function GetProjectDetails(value){
     $.get('get_projectName.php',{id:value},function(data)
     { 
       $('#projectDetail').html(data);
     });
    }
});
```

Comment: thnks, gr8 idea bt this will works when first I select somethng from dropdown and again select first option. Bt at the beginning it will display nothing

Comment: i tried when nothng selected then `if(id='value_of_first_option') {do somethng} else{do next thng}`

Comment: At the begining you need a pass a default value to your php code right? I just showed you how to pass the first value by default. You can tweek your logic to what suits you

Comment: should i change my id or name of first option to match`var firstOptionValue = $("#myHref option:first").val(); ` this line because now `<option value=''>Select</option>`

Comment: use `$("#myHref option:eq(1)").val()`

Answer (score 1):

In the above code you are trying to pass the selected id to php file through $.get() when the dropdown is changed. it is fine, if you want to display all the data when page is loaded then you should have another php which returns all the data in db and doesn't take any value. And write the code as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.get('get_allDataFromDb.php',function(data)
            { $('#projectDetail').html(data);
        });
        $('#myHref').change(function(){
            var value = $('#myHref').val();
            $.get('get_projectName.php',{id:value},function(data)
                 { $('#projectDetail').html(data);
            });
        }); 
        $('#myHref').on('change',function(){
            $('#projectDetail').fadeIn();
        });
});
```

Comment: `$.get('get_allDataFromDb.php',function(data)
            { $('#projectDetail').html(data);
        }); donot works`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your element (e.g. #myHref) don't exist at time when your script . And when you want to show all data on load just call function eg.

> ```
> function getData(){//ajax here}
> getData();
> ```

running. Are there any errors? or something that can help?

Comment: no, there is no any error. now I can output data when I select drop down menu using where clause. N it works perfect. Now I need to display all when page is loaded with out where condition in query....

Comment: ok, i use `$('#myHref').on('change',function(){
        $('#projectDetail').fadeIn();`

Comment: `id = projectDetail` contails all outputs required for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getData(value) {
    params = {};

    if value
        params.id = value;

    $.get('get_projectName.php', params, function (data) {
        $('#projectDetail').html(data);
    });
}
// Get Data onLoad
getData($('#myHref').val());

$('#myHref').on('change',function(){
    getData($('#myHref').val());
    $('#projectDetail').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: How to use params in get_projectName.php

Comment: the current implementation is getData(id_params)
but you can modify it easily by removing the if value block and change to `params = value || {};`  you can easily pass objects as parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$(document).on("change", "#myHref" , function() {

// Your Code Here

});
```

let me know in case it still dont work.

Comment: this will execute data when i select dropdown, also I need to execute when i select nothng i.e when page loads

Comment: in such a case what you can do is, make  some function which get the data dynamicaly as you watnt, and when your document is loaded what you can do is trigger the event for your dropdown change

Comment: yes, I want exactly that bt can't do. example will be best and appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ok , here is my another answer that how you can trigger some event after our document get ready .

hope this will be helpful to you .

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                //Function for AJAX Call
                function GetData(){

                    var value = $('#myHref').val();
                    $.get('get_projectName.php',{id:value},function(data)
                    { 
                        $('#projectDetail').html(data);
                        //
                        $('#projectDetail').fadeIn();
                        // Any other code here you want to write.

                    }); 

                }

                $('#myHref').change();
                //OR you can use
                $("#myHref").trigger("change");

            });            
            $(document).on("change", "#myHref" , function() {
                // Call the function as change evvent is triggered
                GetData();
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: you can also put the function GetData outside the document.ready

Comment: let me know incase you dont understand anywhere.